# proper way of having computed properties or setters for objects within an array in vuex state

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I'm using Vue 3, Vuex 4 and TypeScript. and I have the following models:

```
class CartItem {
  id: number;

  name: string;

  price: number;

  quantity: number;

  // other stuff...
}

class Cart {
  items: CartItem[];

  // other stuff...
}
```

My Vuex store has the following state Schema:

```
type State = {cart: Cart};
```

I have a `Cart` component within which I iterate through the `cart.items` and render CartItem components as seen below:

```
<cart-item v-for="item in cart.items" :key="item.id" />
```

Now, within the `CartItem` component I need access to a **computed** or **getter** for `totalPrice` of a single `CartItem` which returns `quantity * price`. I could define a computed property in the CartItem.vue file but this won't be reusable. This is one of many computed/getters I need.

At first I tried to add TypeScript getters to my `CartItem` model like this:

```
  get totalPrice(): number{
    return this.quantity * this.price;
  }
```

But it didn't return any value when I did:

```html
<span>
{{item.totalPrice}}
</span>
```

It was undefined. I tried to change it from getter to a method. I tried calling it from computed property within my component. No luck yet!

Seems like I should use Vuex getters, but the question is, how can I get totalPrice for each of the `CartItem`s?

Comment: it could be a number of things but console log ```cart.items``` and check if the getter is there and console log the class itself ```CartItem``` and check the transpiled vanilla js code

Comment: @Talal looks like `cart.items` is an array of proxy objects (which I'm not really familiar with yet) and these objects don't really include the typescript getters, they just have the data members. So I'm thinking maybe I should make some functions that get the instance as parameters instead of being a member of them. or maybe a vuex action to call them for me

Comment: I tested in vuex 3 and it worksI dont know about vuex 4